# Snake in Java is not building or growing properly

Tags: java

I'm trying to make snake in Java, I have gotten everything with it to work, but when I try to run the program, the Snake isn't in one long string, but in many different spaced out parts. I've tried searching through every like of code and couldn't identify where anything went wrong.

Here is what I have

**Board.Java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private final int B_WIDTH = 300;
    private final int B_HEIGHT= 300;
    private final int DOT_SIZE = 10;
    private final int ALL_DOTS = 900;
    private final int RANDOM_POS = 29;
    private final int DELAY = 140;
    
    private final int x[] = new int[ALL_DOTS];
    private final int y[] = new int[ALL_DOTS];
    
    private int dots;
    private int apple_x;
    private int apple_y;
    
    private boolean left = false;
    private boolean right = true;
    private boolean up = false;
    private boolean down = false;
    private boolean ingame = true;
    
    private Timer timer;
    
    public Board() {
        CreateBoard();
    }

    private void CreateBoard() {
        
        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setFocusable(true);
        
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(B_WIDTH,B_HEIGHT));
        StartGame();
    }
    
    private void StartGame() {
        dots = 3;
        
        for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
            x[z] = 50 - z * 10;
            y[z] = 50;
        }
        
        LocateApple();
        
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
    
    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
        if (ingame) {           
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.fillRect(apple_x, apple_y, DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE);
            
            for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                    g.fillRect(x[z], y[z], DOT_SIZE, DOT_SIZE);             
            }
        } else {
            gameOver(g);
        }
    }
    
    private void gameOver(Graphics g) {
         String msg = "Game Over";
         Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
         FontMetrics metr = getFontMetrics(small);

         g.setColor(Color.white);
         g.setFont(small);
         g.drawString(msg, (B_WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) / 2, B_HEIGHT / 2);
         
    }

    private void CheckApple() {
        if ((x[0] == apple_x) && (y[0] == apple_y)) {
            dots++;
            LocateApple();
        }
    }
    
    private void move() {
        
        for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {
            x[z] = x[(z - 1)];
            y[z] = y[(z - 1)];
            
        if(left) {
            x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        }
        if(right) {
            x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        }
        if(up) {
            y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        }
        if(down) {
            y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
            }
        }
    }
    
    private void CheckCollision() {

        for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {
            if((z > 4) && (x[0] == x[z]) && (y[0] == y[z])) {
                ingame = false;
            }
        }       
        if (x[0] >= B_WIDTH) {
            ingame = false;
        }
        if (x[0] < 0) {
            ingame = false;
        }
        if (y[0] >= B_HEIGHT) {
            ingame = false;
        }
        if (y[0] < 0) {
            ingame = false;
        }
        if (!ingame) {
            timer.stop();
        }       
    }

    private void LocateApple() {
        
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * RANDOM_POS);
        apple_x = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
        
        r = (int) (Math.random() * RANDOM_POS);
        apple_y = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
}       
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (ingame) {
            
            CheckApple();
            CheckCollision();
            move();
            
        }
        repaint();
    }
    
    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            
            int key = e.getKeyCode();
            
            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (right == false)) {
                left = true;
                up = false;
                down = false;
            }
            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && (left == false)) {
                right = true;
                up = false;
                down = false;
            }
            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && (down == false)) {
                up = true;
                left = false;
                right = false;
            }
            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (up == false)) {
                down = true;
                left = false;
                right = false;
            }           
        }       
    }
}
```

**Game.Java** (main class)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Game extends JFrame {

        public Game() {
            StartUI();
        }
        
        private void StartUI() {
            add(new Board());
            
            setResizable(false);
            pack();
            
            setTitle("Snake");
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame ex = new Game();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
    
}
```

When I try to run the code it behaves very strangely and I can't identify the problem.

Can anyone find what is causing it and what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to see what's going wrong with a correct indentation of the `move` method:

```java
private void move() {
    for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {
        x[z] = x[(z - 1)];
        y[z] = y[(z - 1)];
        
        if(left) {
            x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        }
        if(right) {
            x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        }
        if(up) {
            y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
        }
        if(down) {
            y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
        }
    }
}
```

The head move (`x[0]`, `y[0]`) is inside the `for` loop, making it done several times per move.
You should better move all the body parts first, then move the head.

```java
private void move() {

    // 1) Move the body
    for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {
        x[z] = x[z - 1];
        y[z] = y[z - 1];
    }
    
    // 2) Move the head
    if (left) {
        x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    }
    if (right) {
        x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    }
    if (up) {
        y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    }
    if (down) {
        y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    }
}
```